# three js cube is black...not red

Tags: javascript, three.js

First time trying out three js...my cube is black...I set the colour to red, is there a reason why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Some shapes</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/threejs/build/three.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="output">

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

                var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(8,8,8);

                var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x990000});

                var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

                cube.position.x = -4;
                cube.position.y = 3;
                cube.position.z = 0;

                scene.add(cube);

                camera.position.x = -30;
                camera.position.y = 40;
                camera.position.z = 30;
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);

                $("#output").append(renderer.domElement);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I set the colour in the mesh lambert material...but I don't think I need to do anymore than this? In the browser it comes out black...does it have anything to do with setClearColour perhaps?

Comment: I changed MeshLambertMaterial to MeshBasicMaterial and it worked, I am guessing that because the lambert material colour is probably determined by some sort of light source on the object, since there is no light, the colour is coming out black...

Answer (score 3):

This was my original comment:

I changed MeshLambertMaterial to MeshBasicMaterial and it worked, I am guessing that because the lambert material colour is probably determined by some sort of light source on the object, since there is no light, the colour is coming out black...

I reworked my first try to this:

```
$(function() {
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

                var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

                var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(8,8,8);

                var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x990000});

                var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

                cube.position.x = -4;
                cube.position.y = 3;
                cube.position.z = 0;

                scene.add(cube);

                //add some lighting
                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
                scene.add(ambientLight);

                var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
                spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, -10);

                spotLight.castShadow = true;

                scene.add(spotLight);


                camera.position.x = -30;
                camera.position.y = 40;
                camera.position.z = 30;
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);

                $("#output").append(renderer.domElement);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            });
```

my guess was correct, when using Lambert or Phong materials, you need some lighting, otherwise in the dark, you won't be able to see the colours since the materials react to some lighting.

Comment: This is incredibly fun